# Captive portal using raspberry pi

Tags: macos, apache, raspberry-pi

I am making an captive portal using the apache server:(raspberry pi)

I have 2 ports-> 20.20.20.2 and 10001=>(20.20.20.2-10001)

This is the method I followed:

1. I have: (sudo apt-get update) Installed the necessary updates
2. Installing apache: sudo apt-get install apache2 -y
3. Then I have started the (sudo apachectl start) server.

(Also refer to this article: http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/web-server/apache.md)

And I have entered the IP in the browser but it is redirecting me to the Port 20.20.20.2 but I want it to go to the index.html file(default file ) in the apache server.

Please help! The apache server is running fine but when I connect to the raspberry pi its not redirecting it to the index.html file. Please let me know the possible errors

If you need more information please comment

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I also looked for a solution for captiv portal. A solution that worked for me was ***nodogsplash***.

Instructions and a repository for debian (also Raspian) can be downloaded from the Github page : https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash

Install library for compile

```
sudo apt install git libmicrohttpd-dev
```

Clone Repository

```
git clone https://github.com/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.git
```

Compile and install

```
cd ~/nodogsplash
make
sudo make install
```

Set your configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/nodogsplash/nodogsplash.conf
```

And Reboot the os

I hope this answer helps